# Creating a hyperlink from a file name read from input file to write to a output text file

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, hyperlink

I would like to convert the text name of each of the several files listed on the input text file (compatible with NotePad) to a hyperlink and would like to use the file name as the text display associated with each hyperlink and write the result with the hyperlinks to an output text file (also compatible with NotePAd).

I would lilke to use either VB Script or VB.Net as the programming language.  I cannot find instructions for creating the hyperlink from a character string using either VB Script or VB.Net.  Can someone point me to some relevant documentation?

Comment: Do you mean an `.url` file type? If that's the case, it's a simple text file, with a `[InternetShortcut]` *header*, similar to the initialization files (`.ini`) style: `[Section] [Key] = [Value]`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a file named `input.txt` with this in it

> filename1.txt
>   filename2.txt
>   filename3.txt

then you could use this code to read the lines and write a new file `output.txt`

```vb
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt")
File.WriteAllLines(
    "output.txt",
    lines.Select(Function(line) line.Replace(".txt", "") & vbTab & Path.Combine("\\domain\", line)))
```

which has the filename and a path to the file separated by a tab

> filename1  \\domain\filename1.txt
>   filename2   \\domain\filename2.txt
>   filename3   \\domain\filename3.txt

This deals with a txt file as input and output. The terms `compatible with NotePad` and `use the file name as the text display associated with each hyperlink` are conflicting because notepad will display plain text, not a web page for example. But if you do want something which will render links as titles, you may want to try to write html with HtmlTextWriter

```vb
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt")
Using sw = New StringWriter()
    Using writer As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        For Each line In lines
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, Path.Combine("\\domain\", line))
            writer.RenderBeginTag("A")
            writer.Write(line.Replace(".txt", ""))
            writer.RenderEndTag()
            writer.WriteBreak()
        Next
    End Using
    File.WriteAllText("output.html", sw.ToString())
End Using
```

This would be what you'd see in notepad

```
<a href="\\domain\filename1.txt">filename1</a><br />
<a href="\\domain\filename2.txt">filename2</a><br />
<a href="\\domain\filename3.txt">filename3</a><br />
```

and in a web browser

[image]